# dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract on magento EE

Tags: php, magento, core-data, nginx

I know this questions is asked so many times but none of the answers is working for me this time.

Everytime I try to load my magento EE 1.14.2.0 I get:

```
dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract

Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/receptional/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->setConnection(false)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/receptional/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#2 /var/www/vhosts/receptional/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#3 /var/www/vhosts/receptional/htdocs/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#4 /var/www/vhosts/receptional/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#5 /var/www/vhosts/receptional/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/receptional/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/receptional/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/receptional/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('swimshop', 'store')
#9 /var/www/vhosts/receptional/htdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/receptional/htdocs/index.php(83): Mage::run('swimshop', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

I have tried updating permissions for var and media folder to 777 but no luck, I also tried updating permission of my whole magento to 777 but no luck again. 
Just to let you know that I am on Nginx server if that helps.

Comment: Is this fixed for you?

Comment: Hi there, 
yes, it's fixed.
Since I installed magento using SSH and git so it didn't apply right folder permissions to the nested folder, thus making this difficult to detect.

Answer (score 0):

Though you are able to run chmod -R 777 files permissions, it may not be working properly. This error comes because of file permission issues.

Check if SELinux is in permissive mode or not?

```
sestatus
```

If it is not in permissive mode use following.

Running the following command should fixe the issue.

```
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t <web Directry>
```